# Access-Control-Allow-Origin header spoofing?

Tags: javascript, http

Is it possible for a attacker to spoof the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Or, is it secure enough to protect resource access via the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

I'm trying to make an API key useless on certain domains, like the linked in JS API.

Comment: Just to clarify: what exactly do you mean by "spoof the header?"

Comment: I mean : can you manually send a request with fake origin header? as far as i 've read in these days yes, as also Rook pointed out.

Comment: 'curl --header "Origin: HELLOWORLD" www.google.com' — Boom, request sent w/ random Origin header. It's up to the client (that is: browser) to enforce any restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an attacker can control the access-control-allow-origin header then they can carry out **much worse** attacks than just modify this header element.  For example an attacker could carry out a Man in the Middle attack,  but authentication tokens,  like cookies are a more desirable target.

An attacker could introduce their own access-control-allow-orign header using HTTP Response Splitting, but at this point they can control the entire header and the body. An "allow-orign" doesn't help with the entire Same-Origin Policy is undermined by an XSS vulnerability.